# Uncomfortable computer chair is killing me, is it possible to bring my own?

Tags: work-environment, health, ergonomics

So my office has a very uncomfortable computer chair - I can't seat on it without being in pain after a couple of hours. I have a low height (156 cm), so most medium-sized chairs are uncomfortable, because I can't make them low enough, and, what is harder to cope with, they are too deep, meaning, to be able to touch its back I need to sit in a way my knees are on the chair too which causes even more pain than not using back support at all.

So I've been thinking about buying and bringing my own office chair, more suited for my height and needs. I already feel huge pain in legs and not sure for how much longer I'll be able to take it..

Does anyone has similar experience? What is the proper way to accomplish this?

Comment: It is unfortunate that you are facing this situation. However, it appears you have already made peace with "I've been thinking about buying and bringing my own office chair", so what is the obstacle you are facing?

Answer (score 3):

I believe the more appropriate way to handle this is to speak to your company. Raising it with your manager would be a good starting point, but your company might have someone else more appropriate to bring it to. Certainly the company I work for has gone out and purchased equipment for people's comfort (medical balls to sit on, standing desks, mouse pads etc) and it doesn't seem like a unreasonable request (plus chairs aren't exactly expensive)

Presumably you are aware of what kind of chair you'd need (i.e. one that you use at home?), so ensure you offer a solution and don't just complain. Your request can be made via e-mail or face to face, whatever is more appropriate in your company. E-mail gives you a record of conversation and allows the person you enquire to some thinking time.

Comment: Hopefully, your company is reasonable and will buy you a more suitable chair, but if the company is not immediately open to the idea - get a doctor's note stating that your current situation is adversely affecting your health, and that you need a chair that allows you to sit comfortably and not impact on your spine/legs.

Comment: Agreed for the most part, though high-quality office chairs can be pretty darn expensive.

Answer (score 3):

Yes there is not a problem to buy and bring your own chair. The problem is to prove that you own it when you need to move office or company or someone borrows it or switches it by accident.
So you need to make sure that you have receipts etc needed to prove that it is your property and not the company's. If you want to buy some really expensive chair you'll have lot of hassle to make sure you can actually keep it